# How to send arrow in paramiko in python 3?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, terminal, escaping, paramiko

I automate testing of terminal application running in links browser on remote server. Here I need to send press of an arrow key.

Solution from [How to send an arrow key use paramiko library in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606569/how-to-send-an-arrow-key-use-paramiko-library-in-python)
 (sending f.e. '\e[B' for arrow down) obviously don't work in Python 3.

Is there a way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, should send:

```
KEY_UP = b'\x1b[A'
KEY_DOWN = b'\x1b[B'
KEY_RIGHT = b'\x1b[C'
KEY_LEFT = b'\x1b[D'
```

It works, but it cannot be converted to (python3 default multibyte) string before sending.